# Database Structure Joining Tables with different structures

Tags: php, database, mysqli, cron

I have a scenario and I was wondering what is the most efficient method of joining two different tables with different structures using php and mysqli. I shall start with the preferred outcome and work backwards.

> **Ideally I am hoping to have a table like:**
>
> Product_Id, Product_Description, Product_Cost, Main_Image, alt_Img1,
> alt_img2, alt_img3

What I currently have is two separate tables populated from files retrieved from a feed (actually five+ files but for the purposes of this I have simplified to only the tables in question). So ...

Two tables in question ... Product and Images

> **--Product Table--**
>
> Product_Id, Product_Description, Product_Cost
>
> 1, Some Awesome Product, 10.00
>
> 2, Another Awesome Product, 12.00
>
> 3, Bad Product, 2.00
>
> **--Images Table--**
>
> Product_Id, Image_pos, Image_Name
>
> 1, 1, Pic1.jpg
>
> 1, 2, Pic2.jpg
>
> 1, 3, Pic3.jpg
>
> 2, 1, Frontimg.jpg
>
> 3, 1, Badprod.jpg
>
> 3, 2, Badprod.jpg
>
> and so on....

So Basically I am wanting to join images to products but have the Image_pos = 1 the Main_Image and 2,3,4 in the respective alt_img fields after that.

Assumptions: We are only importing a max of 4 images so any other images can be ignored.
Products without images will need a place holder entry 'placholder.jpg'
All image names are correct and case sensitive.
Both Tables are InnoDB.
Running Multiple Queries is fine.
The Information will be updated daily

Other Info: The data set is relatively big 100k+ records and whilst I have had no problems with other tables, the image table doesn't have a Primary key. This slows down any query's tremendously. How can I resolve this issue with the best speed possible (do I add an incremental primary key? Will this even help?)

I'm thinking that I will need a sql where statement to get the main_image and then iterate over an array to build up alt_img1, alt_img2 etc. but I really am unsure as to how to proceed with the best solution.

Currently I have been using php and I am hoping to automate all of this by cron once all is said and done. Any suggestions on how I should proceed would be greatly appreciated and any pitfalls you experts could see me having would also be helpful.  Thanks. If I have missed anything or you need further info I'm happy to provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean you want a new table that duplicates the data from your two tables, or a VIEW, or a JOIN in a SELECT statement that allows you to retrieve data from both?

Comment: I would like to create a new table based of this information so I can eventually create a CSV based off it. I'm breaking it down I know, but I currently have other queries pulling data from files and building this large table up piece by piece. This images bit is the last piece to the puzzle so to speak.

Comment: Is there a technical or business reason why it needs to be a new table, and not simply a VIEW?

Comment: Well yes, I need it in the table for the CMS / eCommerce Platform. I understand what you are getting at with VIEWS but the complete data set needs to be searchable and indexed and so far joining and creating the large table has been the be best solution apart from this stumbling block. I was hoping I could run a php loop that would iterate over the images table and insert the data in the products table where necessary.

Comment: Well, SELECTs from a VIEW will use indexes that exist on the underlying tables, if that's what your concern is... in many ways, it's a lot easier and a lot more maintainable than building a new table and having to run a PHP script to keep it populated.... and a VIEW will always be up to date

Comment: Sorry mate initially it needs to be a table. There are other fields from other sources that I haven't listed here that will make up the large table (5 files (load data infile) and a select query with 4 joins that runs over tables that are 30+meg in size). The idea is once the table is populated I will generate a CSV from it then run an import cron on the csv into the existing eCommerce platform essentially cutting out the data it doesn't need and merging the data into a single import. It seems convoluted I know but its the way it has to happen due to the poor feed we have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63404/discussion-between-ryan-and-mark-baker).